# PHP JavaScript client WebSocket not able to receive data more than 125 bytes

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, tcpclient

I am using PHP sockets on server side and JavaScript sockets on client side. Handshaking, unmasking and masking is working fine for messages length upto 125 but the problem is, when the server sends data of more than 125 bytes, the client side socket doesn't receive the data and closes automatically.

Here's the code I am using:

```
private function unmask($payload) {
  $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;

  if($length == 126) {
    $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
    $data = substr($payload, 8);
    $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 8) + ord($payload[3]);
  }
  elseif($length == 127) {
    $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
    $data = substr($payload, 14);
    $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 56) + (ord($payload[3]) << 48) + (ord($payload[4]) << 40) + (ord($payload[5]) << 32) + (ord($payload[6]) << 24) + (ord($payload[7]) << 16) + (ord($payload[8]) << 8) + ord($payload[9]);
  }
  else {
    $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
    $data = substr($payload, 6);
    $len = $length;
  }

  $text = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
  }
  return $text;
}

private function encode($text) {
  // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)
  $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
  $length = strlen($text);

  if($length <= 125)
    $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
  elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
    $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
  elseif($length >= 65536)
    $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

  return $header.$text;
}

private function handshake($buffer,$socket,$socket_index) {
  list($resource,$host,$origin,$key) = $this->getSocketKeyFromHeaders($buffer);
  $retkey = base64_encode(sha1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11",true));
  $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: {$retkey}\r\n\r\n";
  $this->handshakes[$socket_index] = true;
  socket_write($socket,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
  echo $this->output("Done handshaking...\n");
}

private function getSocketKeyFromHeaders($req) {
  $req  = substr($req,4); /* RegEx kill babies */
  $res  = substr($req,0,strpos($req," HTTP"));
  $req  = substr($req,strpos($req,"Host:")+6);
  $host = substr($req,0,strpos($req,"\r\n"));
  $req  = substr($req,strpos($req,"Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")+19);
  $key  = trim(substr($req,0,strpos($req,"\r\n")));
  $req  = substr($req,strpos($req,"Origin:")+8);
  $ori  = substr($req,0,strpos($req,"\r\n"));

  return array($res,$host,$ori,$key);
}
```